# CLLocationManager authorization message not show in ios iOS 8.0.1

Tags: ios, ios8

CLLocationManager authorization message not show when i start application i have checked in location service inside device application show but don't have permission.

All things are working fine in ios 7 with xcode 5.1 but issue in Xcode 6.0 with ios 8.0

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
{
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In iOS8 you have to request the user to authorize the access by using `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` or `requestAlwaysAuthorization`.

And you have add either of the keys `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` or `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` with proper messages to the `info.plist`

```
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
{
   [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}
```

Comment: It should work. can you just delete the app and reinstall it. Reset the privacy & location settings also

Comment: I have checked after delete app and reset setting But stile not working
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    
    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
    {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

Comment: Thanks now its working... i missed info.plist setting

Comment: One more query can you please tale me how to check location service enabled or not for application right now i am using following but not working.
if (!locationManager.location) {
}

Comment: [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]